# Google spreadsheet - color alternate rows

Tags: google-sheets, rows

I use a custom formula in conditional formatting for coloring alternate rows as follows: =ISEVEN(Row())

This works fine but I need to apply it to the entire sheet to include new rows. So for example I have a sheet with rows with 100 rows and columns from A to BB. I tried using Sheet!$A$2:$BB for example - but Google won't have it - it automatically changes it to A2:BB100.

This is frustrating - is there really no way to have an entire sheet including any new rows for this? Thank you.

UPDATE: @Max Makhrow's comment solved this for me. Many thanks for this.

Comment: I've made conditional formatting for range A1:H100, then added new rows and formatted range expanded automatically.

Comment: Thanks, @Max Makhrow, you did solve this for me. I would like to mark your comment as ANSWER but it seems I can't. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Mica is there a sample sheet with Max's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [How to Color Alternate Rows or Columns in Google Sheets](http://www.guidingtech.com/49821/alternate-color-google-drive-sheet/)

Comment: Thank you but this is not really what I was looking for. I use the same formula =ISEVEN(Row()) and ISODD(Row()) - that's not the problem. The problem is selecting the entire worksheet range - as it is now we can only select rows that are available in the sheet (if the sheet has 1000 rows, then we can only select A1:BB1000). But if more row are added in addition to 1000, the coloring will not be applied to them. I hope I explained it now.

Comment: Thank you@mrid. Perhaps you meant the same thing as Max Makhrow. Sorry I misunderstood.